# Kafka Consumer fetching only from one partition

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using node-rdkafka  to consume messages from kafka . I ran consumer in cluster mode , but only one consumer seems to be working , rest are not fetching any data from kafka .
here is the status of consumer group [image]

can any one help me to find the issue , why other consumers are not working?

Comment: From the status diagram, it looks like they are fetching data, but slowly. Its hard to comment on why this might be happening unless you share some details about the consumer (configuration etc.)

Comment: I have created consumer  like this `var consumer = new Kafka.KafkaConsumer({
    'group.id': 'calllog6',
    'metadata.broker.list': process.env.KAFKA_SERVERS,
    'enable.auto.commit': false,

}, { 'auto.offset.reset': process.env.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET });



consumer.connect();

consumer
    .on('ready', function() {
        console.log('consumer ready')
        consumer.subscribe(['calllog']);

        setInterval(function() {
            consumer.consume(500);
        }, 1000);
    })`

Comment: even after one consumer finished consuming from partition 6 , other consumers did not fetch anything .